# how to pagination JSONResult in MVC with ajax url data loading?

Tags: json, model-view-controller, jsonresult

I have a problem in pagination with a json result data in MVC.
Below code is my ajax data loading:

```
jQuery.ajax({
        url: "/Products/Search",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            displayData(data);
        },
        error: function (errdata, errdata1, errdata2) { $('#ProductList').html("Error in connect to server" + errdata.responseText); }
```

and my controller `JsonResult` is below:

```
public JsonResult List()
        {
            tbl = db.tblProducts;
            return Json(tbl, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

I can recive data from above ajax data loading successfully, but I can't pagination it.
Please help me.
Thank you.

Comment: Checkout http://www.datatables.net/examples/ajax/index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no code for Pagination,Do you want to do  client side pagination or server side

Thinking your devloping an ASP.Net MVC application

**Server side pagnation** : You can load the specific number of records alone.
Using Skip and Take functionlitys

```
public JsonResult GetOrders(int pagesize, int pagenum)
        {
            var query = Request.QueryString;
            var dbResult = db.Database.SqlQuery<Order>(this.BuildQuery(query));
            var orders = from order in dbResult
                        select new Order
                        {
                            ShippedDate = order.ShippedDate,
                            ShipName = order.ShipName,
                            ShipAddress = order.ShipAddress,
                            ShipCity = order.ShipCity,
                            ShipCountry = order.ShipCountry
                        };
            var total = dbResult.Count();
            orders = orders.Skip(pagesize * pagenum).Take(pagesize);
            var result = new
            {
                TotalRows = total,
                Rows = orders
            };
            return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

Client side pagination : Load the entire records to your view  from there implement pagination

Sample code  : http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/5xr2x/

Answer (score 0):

```
Database db = new Database();
public int PageSize = 5;
public int VisiblePageCount = 5;

public JsonResult Search(int page = 1)
    {
        var model = new ModelName();
        var tbl = db.tblProducts;

        var renderedScheduleItems =(tbl.Skip((page - 1) * PageSize)
                .Take(PageSize)
                .ToList());
        model.Products = renderedScheduleItems;
        model.PagingDetail = new PagingDetail()
        {
            CurrentPage = page,
            ItemsPerPage = PageSize,
            TotalItems = items.Count,
            VisiblePageCount = VisiblePageCount
        };

        return Json(model, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet); 
    }
```